# CSS Javascript Change the button property

Tags: css

Im  using reference from here : http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/showhide-content/ and confused with the javascript

I want if I click  see more, the see more wont become invisible, only activate the link

PS: I tried this at jsfiddle but dunno why didnt working, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/cfp35/

The code:

```
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
            home
            </a>


      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
         <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.more {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
```

Comment: Could you please write the URL of your fiddle?

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/cfp35/` here

Comment: Well, in your fiddle there's no JavaScript, the `showHide` function isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. If #shID element is not displayed, let it display.

No change in the buttom at all.

```
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if ((document.getElementById(shID).style.display == 'none')||(document.getElementById(shID).style.display == '')) {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Success, but this make me must click the shID twice at first? after that its okay

Comment: like : 1st click, nothing happen, 2nd click, show content, 3rd click, hide content, 4th click, show content

Comment: Amendment made, try it again.